# X-Requested-With Header is Missing Only On Production - AWS ALB + ECS + EC2

Tags: jquery, laravel, cors, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I can see the following `xhr` request in the Google Chrome Developer tools (in production website).

[image]

But when I inspect the request, I cannot see the `X-Requested-With:` header as I see in my development environment. (See below image in development website)

[image]

As a result of this, I don't get a `JSON` response from the production server (In development, I get a `JSON` response - You can see it from the icons of the above two xhr)

### Question

How do I make sure `X-Requested-With:` is sent with the request in production?

*(Or at least help me to understand the issue here...)*

### Notes

- In production, the server is behind AWS ALB - Connecting to ECS Containers running on EC2 capacity provider.
- Application is Laravel based using 'Metronic' theme
- If the server did not allow `X-Requested-With` with header using its `CORS` policy, then jQuery will not send that `X-Requested-With` header. I suspect somehow the server is not allowing that header.
- I use containers for development (use git for version control) - therefore the code is same on production and development.

### What I have tried

- Tried refresh my learning about CORS
- Tried to find the CORS setting in ALB - not found
- Tried to find the CORS settings in ECS tasks - not found
- Tried to manually add the header

```
$.ajax({
     url: "http://your-url...",
 headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
});
```

- That was not possible as this request was made by a third-party script (https://datatables.net/)

*Please let me know if you need more information to help me solve this issue. Thank you.*

### References

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/src/ajax/xhr.js#L44

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/js/bootstrap.js#L11

Comment: This is entirely a function of the software you are running. The JavaScript software running in the web browser is going to be adding the `X-Requested-With` header to the request that the browser then sends to the server. You need to be focusing on the software configuration instead of the AWS server (ALB/ECS) configuration, as the AWS part is not relevant to the issue here. Also, the CORS settings are going to be in Laravel, or maybe in Nginx or Apache if you are running one of those in front of Laravel.

Comment: Since it worked correctly on development and this happened on AWS production setup, I assumed this is something to do with AWS settings. Also, I can recall when setting up Cloudfront there was a place to add CORS headers/settings. I'll check again configuration/code in Laravel, Nginx, etc. Thanks @MarkB

Comment: You didn't mention anywhere in your question about using CloudFront. You can indeed  configure CORS in CloudFront. I'm not sure how that would be related to the web browser sending or not sending an HTTP header however. Did you verify in the browser web console that the header wasn't being sent by the browser in production?

Comment: I'm sorry that my comment was misleading. The Cloudfront setting I mentioned was not for this project. My intention was to ask you whether ALB/ECS/Task do have such kind of settings (because I am not much familiar with AWS). Thanks again for your time on this @MarkB

Comment: I added a third point under 'Notes' explaining what I found regarding CORS and jQuery. @MarkB

Comment: No, ALB/ECS/Tasks just pass the HTTP requests through to the software you are running, they do not have custom CORS settings.

Comment: You need to perform more debugging in the browser console, in production, to verify that the header isn't actually being sent in production. You can also verify there what CORS requests the browser is making, and what response it is getting.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. It seems this is not related to AWS/ALB/ECS/Tasks. I have updated the question with new information.